# Update the record which is being inserted/updated using a trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I update a full name as the combination of the first name and last name of the same record which is being updated/inserted using a trigger?

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateFullName
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.full_name := :NEW.first_name || ' ' || :NEW.last_name;
END;
/
```

Though a view would probably be more appropriate in this case

Comment: Or a [virtual column](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Virtual+Columns) in 11g; shame the OP specified 10g.

Comment: True, they fit perfectly in this case.